# Cant build React app - pipeline fails miserably

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, azure-pipelines

```
 ---> Running in 0e34d471598d

> myproject@1.0.0 build /app
> node scripts/build.js

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.html
  Searched in: /app/public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@1.0.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-05T14_49_57_665Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build ;' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build ;' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

So there is the error "can't find file" but actually THERE IS a `public` directory with the `index.html` file inside. I don't know why this is happening...

**Edit**: Im adding the docker file used in config pipe

```
# -- Base node --
FROM node:13.7-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
ARG BUILD_ENV
RUN npm run build ;

# -- final build --
FROM nginx:1.17.8-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice you are running this on docker, so you did wrong on docker during copy your react app directory to docker container.

You have not added your `Dockerfile` code here

So we suggest you to fix your dockerfile first. Also check your `.dockerignore` file and debug getting into docker container, if the directory exist there or not

So your docker file should be similar to this

```
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the docker file

Comment: Thank you again, the problem was with `.dockerignore` file as you said, there was "public" dir excluded. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this (Not `. /app`):

```
# Copy other project files and build
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
```